# How can I get context in Android Jetpack Compose using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-context, android-jetpack

I have an Android Jetpack Compose application in Kotlin with a function requiring context. The function is as seen below.

```kotlin
fun copyDataBase(context: Context, OUTPUT_DB_PATH: String, DB_NAME: String) {
    // Path to output database path (application database path).
    var APP_DB_FILE_PATH = OUTPUT_DB_PATH + "/" + DB_NAME

    // Path to input database file.
    var INPUT_DB_PATH = "database/" + DB_NAME

    // Open your local db as the input stream
    val databaseInput: InputStream = context.getAssets().open(INPUT_DB_PATH)

    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    val databaseOutput: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(APP_DB_FILE_PATH)

    // Transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
    var length: Int
    while (databaseInput.read(buffer).also { length = it } > 0) {
        databaseOutput.write(buffer, 0, length)
    }

    // Close the streams
    databaseOutput.flush()
    databaseOutput.close()
    databaseInput.close()
}
```

And then in the main activity I do this.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // How can I get context to supply to the function?
        copyDataBase(context, DB_PATH, DB_NAME)

        setContent {
            Column() {
                TopAppBar(title = { Text(text = "Nyimbo") })
                ScrollableColumn(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(10.dp)) {
                    lyricsPageComposable(lyricsMap = songMap)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get context to supply it to the function in the main activity? From which Jetpack Compose namespace is it imported from?

I have tried `import android.content.Context` but this requires initialization of which I can't figure out how to do it.

The idea is to copy the pre-populated SQLite database from assets directory into the application at first run.

Comment: Cannot you call your db method after setting your content?

Comment: @jeelVankhede I'm not sure what you mean by `after setting your content'. The function requires the ```context``` to start with, no matter where it is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I get context to supply it to the function in the main activity?

Where you have that call, use `this`. An `Activity` is a `Context`.

Ideally, this code would not be in an activity — it would be in a repository, or at worst a viewmodel, with the actual disk I/O being performed on a background thread.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm learning Android development, could elaborate further, what do you mean by repository?

Comment: @Amani: See https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-repository?hl=en#5 and https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide from the docs.

Comment: @Amani: FWIW, I strongly recommend that you put Jetpack Compose aside for a while and come back to it in, say, 2022. Compose is in an early alpha state right now. It is not all that easy for experienced Android developers to pick up, due to modest (and sometimes outdated) documentation and other resources. I cannot recommend it to newcomers to Android right now. Wait for it to become stable (hopefully in late 2021) and worry about it then. In the meantime, focus on learning Android using existing resources and the classic `View` system.

Comment: @CommonsWare is it ok to use jetpack compose now?

Comment: @divine: That depends on your definition of "ok".  There is a stable release, and there are reports of developers using it for shipping apps. There are also reports of a fair number of bugs and limitations. Plus, while a fair bit has been written about Compose UI, it is still a tiny fraction of what has been written about the classic `View` system. Going by the [technology adoption lifecycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_adoption_life_cycle), I would say we are in the "Innovators" section heading towards "Early Adopters". If you feel that fits you, start composing!

Comment: @CommonsWare i have started composing, currently working on a project ground up.  i'm stuck with a doubt while integrating places sdk with composable. fragments are required for places sdk. is it possible to wrap a fragment or an activity inside a composable function?

Comment: @divine: "is it possible to wrap a fragment or an activity inside a composable function?" -- no, sorry. You can define the UI of a fragment or an activity as a composable, but that is as close as you are going to come.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks a lot for the inputs. i will go ahead with navigation graph using fragments

Comment: I'm using Sqlite (I'm sorry but I do not like Room and I'm familiar with basic Sqlite) for my app and have Dagger Hilt function to provide the database but this function takes a `Context` as an argument. It was fine when I was running Android Tests on it (can use the `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext` but now that I'm trying to actually run the app I get an error saying I need a Dagger Hilt `@Provides` function for Context. But I don't know how to get it outside of a `Composable` function.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, I saw `ApplicationContext` somewhere and so looked at that but it was a Hilt annotation. So I just guessed and added that annotation before my "context" parameter in my "provides" function and that actually worked! So my Dagger Hilt "provides" function for my db is this: `fun provideMyDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context): MyDbAdapter {`